# Change ocurrence inside a string

Tags: php

I am needing to change occurrence of string or numbers in php. In this situation, I need to change this, if it happens:

```
[code:154545edppy] 
    // my code here
[/code]
```

to this

```
[code]
    // my code here
[/code]
```

I need to verify if letters and strings appear inside de opening block code. I am trying to do this with str_replace, but it's not working.

my code now:

```
$text = "[code:54as] [/code]"; 

$text = str_replace("[code: {(\d)}{(\w)}]", "[code]", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/code: {(\d)}{(\w)}]", "[/code]", $text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: Show your code example.

Comment: the code is there now

Comment: chris, I need to change any ocurrence of strings and numbers, after the word 'code'. It was a example, in the real case, the codes are different. With pleg_replace, I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace` is static. Use `preg_replace` with a regex and you can accomplish your task.

Something like:

```
$text = "[code:54as] [/code]";
echo preg_replace('~(\[/?.*?):.*?\]~', '$1]', $text);
```

Should do it.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/643544
Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/mD1bM3/1

If you only want to replace numbers and letters after the `:` use a character class in place of the second `.*?`. `[A-Za-z\d]*?`.

Comment: Hello chris85, your code works in this example. I thought that would works in my real case, but something didn't work. In my real case, the ocurrence that i need to change is this: [code:54as='joseph_willians']. The code must  change to solve this?

Comment: What are you expecting that to become `[code]`? If so it should work as is, https://eval.in/643545.

Comment: yes, that is it! I will see my code better, thank you guy!